# Retrieving SharePoint file version properties from the web API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, version-history

I'm trying to access the properties (column/field metadata) from old file versions in a document library, via SharePoint's web API.

I can successfully query the library to get a list of files with their current versions using `https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/[sitecollection]/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/[sitecollection]/[libraryname]')/files`, which exposes the URL for querying the file versions and file properties for each file in the library:

```
.../_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/[sitecollection]/[libraryname]/[filename]')/Versions
.../_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/[sitecollection]/[libraryname]/[filename]')/Properties
```

Unfortunately I can't find a way of getting the properties for a particular *version* of a given file. I've tried calling the `Properties` and `ListItemAllFields` endpoints for a file version (using both `GetFileByServerRelativeUrl()` and the `_api/SP.FileVersione[guid]` URL returned by the `/Versions` call), as well as providing the virtual location of the file version `_vti_history/[version]/[libraryname]/[filename]` as the argument for `GetFileByServerRelativeUrl()`, but all result in errors.

I've checked the [SharePoint Files and Folders REST API documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_FileVersion) and there seems to be only a small subset of properties available for file versions, compared with normal files. Neither `Properties` nor `ListItemAllFields` are among them.

Where should I go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see, neither the SPListItemVersion nor SPListItemVersionCollection object type are available in the client object model / web API interfaces.

I suggest you to use the good-old web services, like the [Lists.GetVersionCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getversioncollection(v=office.12).aspx) method to access the required information from the client side.

For [example](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20019/get-meta-data-from-a-previous-version-of-a-document-through-webservice-in-moss-2/20022#20022) (assuming you are using C# on the client side):

```
WSLists.Lists listService = new WSLists.Lists();
listService.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
XmlNode result = listService.GetVersionCollection(
    "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx", "[ITEM ID]", "[FIELD NAME]");
string outerXml = result.OuterXml;
```

Further samples can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957546/sharepoint-getversioncollection-how-to-identity-which-version) or [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27346/how-to-programmatically-retrieve-item-version-history-from-client).

Alernatively, you could use the [get document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms442345.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method of the FrontePage RPC Services, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738433/get-versions-when-using-getlistitem-in-sharepoint), although that is even less trivial as the web service based approach.

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for. Is it possible to request multiple field values simultaneously using `Lists.GetVersionCollection`? I've tried including multiple `<strFieldName>` nodes in the SOAP request, but only the first value is returned. I have the field value I was originally after, but I don't know which version it comes from.

Comment: The first *further samples* link you provided indicates this isn't possible, and multiple requests to `GetVersionCollection` are required.